Typescript generic type with constraint on each property
I need to create a generic function which will loop over properties (key, value) of TOrderBy object and console log a property (ordinality) of the value;
type Entries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];

interface ISortableItem {
  ordinality: number;
}

class SortClass {
  name: ISortableItem;
  population: ISortableItem;
}

function sortObject<TSort>(obj: TSort) {
  const objects = Object.entries(obj) as Entries<TSort>;

  for (const [key, value] of objects) {
    console.log(value.ordinality);
  }
}

Typescript compiler is giving error on value.ordinality of course.
is it possible to set a constraint on TSortso that all its properties is supposed to implement ISortableItem ?

Yes, you can constrain the TSort type parameter to Record<keyof TSort, ISortableItem> (using Record<K, V> to mean "an object with properties of type V at keys of type K"):
function sortObject<
  TSort extends Record<keyof TSort, ISortableItem>
>(obj: TSort) {
  const objects = Object.entries(obj) as Entries<TSort>;

  for (const [key, value] of objects) {
    console.log(value.ordinality); // okay
  }
}
sortObject(new SortClass()) // okay

That's a recursive constraint (it depends on TSort).

It is conceptually similar to constraining to an index signature like {[k: string]: ISortableItem}, but interfaces and class instances don't get implicit index signatures (see microsoft/TypeScript#15300) so you'd end up with errors using SortClass:
function sortObjectIdxSig<
  TSort extends { [k: string]: ISortableItem }
>(obj: TSort) { 
  const objects = Object.entries(obj) as Entries<TSort>;

  for (const [key, value] of objects) {
    console.log(value.ordinality); // still okay
  }
}

sortObjectIdxSig(new SortClass()) // error
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'SortClass'

Playground link to code
